# How do I resolve the issue of dynamic image paths in nuxt 3 my images are not displaying on browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

dynamic image paths that I am using. I have also used require but it shows an error require undefined

`` <img :src="`../assets/images/${director.image}`" :alt="director.name"> ``

but when i use _nuxt then it will work

`` <img :src="`_nuxt/assets/images/${director.image}`" :alt="director.name"> ``

page script

```
data() {    
 return {       
directors: [         
{           
image: "directorsImg1.png",         
},         
{           
image: "directorsImg2.png",         
},        
 {           
image: "directorsImg3.png",         
}       
]     
};   
},   
methods: {     
toggleModal(director)
 {       
this.selectedDirector = director;       
this.showModal = !this.showModal;     
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A full file directory is required when you use a path from a variable

```
<template>
    <img :src="showImageIndex === 1 ? Img1 : Img2"/>
</template>


<script setup>

import Img1 from '../assets/images/Img1.png';
import Img2 from '../assets/images/Img2.png';

const showImageIndex = ref(1);

<script>
```

---

The reason why `_nuxt/...` works is you are using a static path just like using a path from CDN, which is none of `vite`'s business, the images have already been bundled by `vite` in `_nuxt` folder. When you run this in prod mode, the random hash tail will be added for static files, and this approach will not work.

Comment: tried this but its not working. It showed that No match found for location with path '../assets/images/Img1.png'; but its the exact directory path of my project